# Having ViewModel call Actions instead of executing Commands and publishing events?

Tags: c#, mvvm

In this hypothetical question, let's say the ViewModel publishes a rather complex event that the View subscribes to. The View then manipulates multiple screen elements based on the state within that event. For example, several buttons are made visible/hidden, or enabled/disabled, or maybe a storyboard is started.

```
// purely as an example:
public class SomeEvent
{
    public bool ShouldShowAddButton { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldShowDeleteButton { get; set; }

    public bool AddButtonEnabled { get; set; }

    public bool DeleteButtonEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Since the VM does not know anything about the View, it can't actually reach in and do these things and instead relies on the event. Standard MVVM practice, I think. (Another option would be to make each of these items be their own published event, sent one after another.)

However, what if the VM could call into the View without knowing anything about the View?

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Action OnShowAddButton { get; set; }
    public Action OnShowDeleteButton { get; set; }
    ...etc

    private void OnSomeStateChange()
    {
        // here, we'd normally publish the SomeEvent class
        // instead, we could just call OnShowAddButton (or whatever) instead
    }
}

public class MyView
{
    public MyView()
    {
        this.myViewModel.OnShowAddButton = () => ...;
        ...etc
    }
}
```

Is there a reason this would be frowned upon, other than not being "typical" of MVVM design? As far as I can tell, it's still maintaining the correct level of separation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this variation is mixing a bit of MVC with a bit of MVVM, although it's none of both. So, the `Model-View` part of the pattern is solved in your proposal by injecting the models straight into the view implementation and then send some kind of commands, via events.

You then need to solve or go around the `View-Model` part of the pattern by either providing properties in the model that can be set directly by the view, or by exposing some events in the view and do the same kind of injection in the model.

I think it will get ugly. Even if the model is only a set of observable entities and you control them from somewhere else (the controller? :)).

I can already see the code, countless events and properties mixed and mingled... But it all depends on how complicated your UI will become, how many views you will have and how complex will they get. In a view with 10+ buttons and/or inputs I think is a bad idea to go with this approach.

I say that as long as you do not have a dedicated MVVM infrastructure, like WPF or HTML, there's no point in implementing your own. You can't get to that beautiful degree of separation only with a hand-coded framework. You need some support to entirely separate the UI code from the model, do bindings and so on.

Perhaps you can comment some more on what you want to use it. If you need it for a client framework (like HTML/JS) or for a Windows Forms implementation then there may be some dedicated solutions you could use, or better, some easier paths you could take.

This all comes from a guy who implemented an MVP variation on top of ASP.NET Web Forms. If I only could turn back time.

Comment: This question came up in a real-world C#+XAML project.

Comment: @moswald: Then I think it's completely OK, since you're only, let's say, extending existing MVVM capabilities. I had the impression you're  writing something from scratch on top of something that wasn't made with separation of concerns in mind.